# how to ignore parent css opacity which is dynamic and forcefully applying on child span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below I have a text which is a nested span. I just want to apply opacity to the first word `Hello` only. but, the opacity is changing to nested span also i.e `STOP`.

**How to ignore the dynamic css changes of parent element?**

```js
let txt = document.getElementById("txt")

setInterval(() => {
    txt.style.opacity = txt.style.opacity == 1 ? 0.2 : 1
},500)
```

```html
<span id="txt" style="font-size: 50px;">
  Hello
  <span style="opacity : 1">STOP</span>
</span>
```

Comment: you cannot ignore (in any way) an opacity applied to the parent. You need to do what you want differently

Comment: You need to put `Hello` in a separate span and change the opacity of that new span.